# Site to Site connection with VPN Gateway & NAT Rules

Tags: azure, vpn, gateway

I have 2 Tenants in Azure, within Tenant 1 I have a Vnet/Snet with 2 VM’s VM1 (10.114.202.92) VM2 (10.114.202.94)
Tenant 1 is having a vnet peering with vnet 2 where I have vnet/GatewaySubnet and my VPN Gateway.
My VPN Gateway has a public IP : 108.142.240.204 and Local Network Gateway Public IP (213.144.3.248) Address Space (217.7.130.224/27) to establish site to site connection to an on Prem Site.
The goal is, that Tenant 1 and Onprem Site can communicate over Tenant 2 where I have the vpngw.
Now the problem is that Onprem Site allows only traffic to them from IP’s from following subnet 198.18.3.244/30  because Traffic coming from 10.114.x.x my overlap with their internal IP’s
Now im struggling to define needed NAT Rules. Is someone able to help me out ?
[Overal solution Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCvQS.png)

[NAT RULES i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rkUg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAT rules to translate the source IP address into a legitimate IP address range that is allowed by your on-premises site. When traffic is coming from your VNet.

You can set up a NAT rule in Tenant 2's VPN gateway to translate traffic coming from the VNet in Tenant 1's source IP address 10.114.XXXX to an IP address in the 198.18.XXXrange like below:

Created NAT rule like below:

[image]

Created connections:

[image]

Try to associate the NAT rules with each connection add your local network gateway and select ingress NAT rule and Egress NAT rule like below:

[image]

***Note*** that NAT is supported on the the following SKUs: *VpnGw2~5, VpnGw2AZ~5AZ.*  You can check the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-howto#nat-limitations) and supported NAT features

Set up a new public IP address resource in Tenant 2 that will be utilised for NAT translation and Create a new NAT rule in the VPN gateway of Tenant 2 that translates the source IP address of traffic coming from the VNet in Tenant 1 to the public IP address and Update the VPN connections between Tenant 2 and your on-premises location so that traffic from Tenant 1 is routed through the public IP address created as the source IP address.

**References:**

[Configure NAT on Azure VPN Gateway - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-howto)

[About NAT on VPN Gateway - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-overview)